# Is Feature Testing the same thing as Regression Testing?

Tags: testing

I googled about this and the descriptions for both types of testing seem to be very similar but I am not sure if they are both the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Feature testing" and "Regression testing" are two slightly different terms.

*Feature testing* is a testing of some functionality, which is typically limited within some logical area. For example you want to test whether the "Like" button on Facebook works properly. The testing activities related to that "Like" button can be named "Feature testing". I would also treat the word "feature" in "feature testing" term as just a piece of functionality.

*Regression testing* is a process of making sure that changes into existing database didn't cause new defects. In case of regression testing of "Like" button on Facebook, you would test that after each update of button's functionality is still works as expected.

I would also say that term "Feature testing" doesn't belong to the terms which are used "officially", since "feature" can be everything and therefore it has too broad meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Feature testing means test a specific functionality or requirement working properly or not.

Regression Testing means to test the impact of that implemented feature or requirement on other functionality.
Simply the impact of modified code on unmodified code.

Answer (score 0):

Feature testing and Regression testing are different.

**Feature Testing:** Test to ensure a specific or new feature works as intended.

**Regression Testing:** Test the whole application to make sure that there is no impact on the current features due to the new changes/features.